# Mean Value Theorem with a constant

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider a function $f$ and a point $a$. Suppose that there is a number $K$ such that
$g(x) = f(a) + K(x − a)$ satisfies

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) − g(x)}{x-a} = 0 $$

Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f′(a) = K$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Can you please share your thoughts on the problem and explain what you've tried? This will help people write a response that's actually relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

What it means to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $a$? It means to show that the limit

$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

exists. In that case look that we need to make $g(x)$ appear there, so that we can use the hypothesis. But that is easy, since $g(x)=f(a)+K(x-a)$ you have that $f(a)=g(x)-K(x-a)$. In that case, you have

$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-(g(x)-K(x-a))}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)+K(x-a)}{x-a},$$

however, we have that the following limit exists

$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{x-a}=0,$$

and also, it's trivial to see that this limit also exists

$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{K(x-a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}K=K,$$

in that case, by a standard theorem about limits, we have that

$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{x-a}+\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{K(x-a)}{x-a}=K$$

and since this limit exists and equals $K$ we have $f$ differentiable at $a$ with $f'(a)=K$.

I tried to explain everything in detail. I hope this helps you out.